# Breaking up a PHP webpage

Tags: php, html

So I've created a php webpage with a `head` section that links to some bootstrap css files and my custom css file. This webpage also has a `foot` division that links to the necessary jQuery and bootstrap JavaScript files. That's all fine and dandy: I know it works because when I launch this .php in firefox, I can see that Bootstrap has taken control and stylized the text. The problem occurs when I try to break this webpage up into components...

I've created a separate `head.html` and `foot.html` which include the same content as before they were broken up, and on the .php page I use the following include statements:

`<?php include '../components/head.html'; ?>`

`<?php include '../components/foot.html'; ?>`

Now when I launch the php from my browser, the links clearly haven't worked because the text is not styled. Upon choosing to "view source" of the .php, I see that it has not included the markup from `head.html` or `foot.html`, and instead I still see the literal `<?php include '';>` statements. What have I done wrong? I know the relative filepaths are correct, so perhaps it has something to do with the fact I'm trying to launch the php page locally? Perhaps the components should be .php instead of .html? I really don't know.

Additional info: Win7, tried using notepad++ because Dreamweaver keeps giving me FTP errors every time I ask to "preview in browser"

Comment: You will need a web server to run PHP code. Your browser is not capable of running it.

Comment: download xamp and read the tutorials on it

Comment: Since you are running windows, install wamp http://www.wampserver.com/en/  and move your files into the 'www' folder it creates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should have a webserver installed along with PHP. You  may use [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [wampp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). If you simply open a php file in your browser then it will not execute the PHP statements instead will display the code as it is.

Except for not having a web server along with PHP installed in your system you have done nothing wrong as I see.

The head.html and foot.html can be html files and not .php files that would not be an issue till the file containing the include statment is .php file.

Comment: Ahhh I should've known. I set up a webserver with 000webhost but I must be accessing it with wrong username/pass info, which should explain why Dreamweaver was giving me a FTP error! Thank you